IRS IRC 403(b) type pension annuity plan - Roll Over monthly payments to IRA - how can it be done and best practices
Thanks to Daniel G. posted a similar question which the answer was clear but I need the next steps on how to rollover the monthly pension payments into an IRA. My plan allows both direct and indirect rollover, but direct rollover is a lump-sum which is not favorable and not my intent. My intent is to use the indirect rollover within 60 days rule but my plan will withhold 20% taxes which I'll have to reconcile at the end of year and make up the 20% with other funds first.
The question remains, is this allowed by the IRS with a 403b type of retirement annuity plan?  Based on this link posted by JohnFx to answer Daniel G.'s question, it seems like periodic payments are not eligible for rollover even though the link points to "International taxpayers", but does that also apply to US citizen taxpayers?

This question is similar to: Can I move monthly pension distributions into a traditional IRA?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In what way does your question differ from the one you linked to? The answer "72(t) distributions are not eligible" refers to the distributions, not the plan. It doesn't matter if it's 401(a) or 403(b).
